# ClientClosedError when using Redis client in Node.js app for caching

Tags: node.js, redis

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const redis = require('redis');

const port = 3000;
const DEFAULT_EXPIRATION = 3600;

const redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Redis error:', error);
});

redisClient.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Redis server');
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get("/photos", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const albumId = req.query.albumId;
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
            { params: { albumId } }
        );

        redisClient.set('photos', JSON.stringify(data));
        redisClient.expire('photos', DEFAULT_EXPIRATION);

        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching photos:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch photos" });
    }
});

app.get("/photos/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const photoId = req.params.id;
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${photoId}`
        );

        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching photo:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch photo" });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is the code in my index.js Client and this is the error that i am facing : return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
^

ClientClosedError: The client is closed

I imported the createClient method but that too didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to Redis once you create the client:

```js
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Redis error:', error);
});

await redisClient.connect();
```